# What is the difference between an ordered list and an array from a theoretical perspective?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, html-lists

Is there any difference, or are they two terms for the same thing?

Comment: What it has to do with HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are some similarities between arrays and lists, they are used for different purposes.

An array is a contiguous segment of memory, and a list is just a bunch of nodes, each one has the pointers to the "next" node (and also to the "previous" node, in the case of bidirectional lists).

Arrays efficiently - in O(1) - support random access (i.e. by arbitrary given index i), but deleting/inserting an element into an array is slow - O(n), because you have to move all elements after deleting/inserting element. 
Lists, on the other hand, do not support efficient random access (while supporting efficient consecutive traversal), but inserting and deleting is fast - O(1).

Look at this picture: [image]:
and at [this link](http://www.necessaryandsufficient.net/2008/05/differences-between-arrays-and-linked-lists/) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and lists are different data structures. Arrays are not necessarily ordered.

Performance wise, maintaining an ordered list is pretty expensive: O(N) insert, delete, but you can do searches faster than O(N) (using something like binary search). With a regular array, search is O(N). With arrays, you can do random access of a member in O(1), while this takes O(N) in an list.

Answer (score 0):

The items in an array are not necessarily in any particular order.

In general, it is possible to add items to a particular point in the list more swiftly than it is possible to add a new item in an array at an equivalent point.  (In the array, you have to shuffle other entries around; in a list, you simply adjust appropriate pointers in at most 3 elements.)  Similarly for deleting elements from lists and arrays.

Access to the N<sup>th</sup> item in a list takes O(N) time but is O(1) time for an array.

Comment: So an array is a hardware (or implementation)-based concept while an ordered list is an abstract data type?

Comment: Linked lists are implementation-based too(albeit one may argue that they are a bit more "abstract" than arrays). BTW, abstract data type is, roughly speaking, an interface that your data structure have to support. And it is not that hard to make arrays and linked lists implement the same interface(look at ArrayList vs LinkedList in Java, for example). Although, the efficiency of key operations: insert, delete and [](access at given index i) will be vastly different.